# MongoEngine - Another user is already authenticated to this database. You must logout first

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

Can anyone please explain why I am getting error **Another user is already authenticated to this database. You must logout first** when connecting to MongoDB using [Flask MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine)?

```
from mongoengine.connection import get_db
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_restful import Api

def init_db():
    return MongoEngine()

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)
app.config.from_object('conf.settings')
db = init_db()
db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/health_check')
def on_health_check():
    try:
        db = get_db()
        db.command('dbstats')

        return jsonify(
            status=200
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('on_health_check() exception -> {}'.format(str(e)))
        abort(500, 'Could not connect to database')


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

conf/settings.py:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'mongodb://username:password@mongo-rep-mongodb-replicaset-0.local:27017,mongo-rep-mongodb-replicaset-1.local:27017/db_name?replicaSet=whatever'
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:5000/health_check`, it always throws the `Exception` with message as I described above.

Comment: opened a bug on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was running into the same issue today, but ended up resolving it by installing a previous version of pymongo, e.g. pip install pymongo==3.4.0 instead of the latest version 3.7.0. There might be a bug...

Comment: You saved my day! I changed to `pymongo==3.6.1` also works.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I changed mongo from standard to replica set.
all my application machines started throwing this error after restarting the application.

> Another user is already authenticated to this database. You must
>   logout first

when I restarted my application machines. it was working fine.

very weird, but posting here since it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

[root@vm-lw-basic-idc-monitor-p01 home]# pip show

> `Metadata-Version: 2.0
>       Name: pymongo
>       Version: 3.7.0
>       Summary: Python driver for MongoDB <http://www.mongodb.org>
>       Home-page: http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver
>       Author: Bernie Hackett
>       Author-email: bernie@mongodb.com
>       Installer: pip
>       License: Apache License, Version 2.0
>       Location: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
>       Requires:
>       Classifiers:
>       Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
>       Intended Audience :: Developers
>       License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
>       Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X
>       Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows
>       Operating System :: POSIX
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 2
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 3
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
>       Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython
>       Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy
>       opic :: Database
>   You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`
>
> pip install pymongo-3.5

我卸载之前的pymongo-3.7就好了,安装原先的3.5就好用的。。。。